# Use path params in serverless framework 1.0

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I want to use the path param `/customer/{customerId}` of a **GET** request in order to query a customer using AWS Lambda:

```
functions:
  createCustomer:
    handler: handler.createCustomer
    events:
    - http:
        path: customer
        method: post
  readCustomer:
    handler: handler.readCustomer
    events:
    - http:
        path: customer
        method: get
```

How do I have to define the path param in order to pass it to my AWS Lambda function using **serverless framework 1.0**?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Define in serverless.yml

```
readCustomer:
  handler: handler.readCustomer
  events:
    - http:
        path: customer/{customerId}
        method: get
```

Access `customerId` in code

```
const customerId = event.pathParameters.customerId;
```

Comment: Note that it's in 'event.pathParameters' because with AWS Lambda proxy integration, API Gateway maps the entire client request to the input 'event' parameter of the backend Lambda function, as described at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-input-format

Answer (score 3):

change path name

```
path: customer/{customerId}
```

Change your handler.js file

```
module.exports.createCustomer= function(event, context) {

{ message: 'Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!', event }

// you can write your logic here


};
```

Comment: I can create the resource, that works! But the path param does not seem to be passed to the Lambda function ... I get an "message": "The provided key element does not match the schema"

Comment: Check it again . if want register customer using some database you can write code here

Comment: Thank you, I have just solved the issue with your help!

Answer (score -3):

**# Solution**

1. Define the path param - for instance customerId - in `serverless.yml`:

`path: customer/customerId`

2. In API Gateway, under your API `/customer/{customerId}` go to **Integration Request** and create a new **Body Mapping Template** which responds to `application/json`and has the following content:

`{ "customerId": "$input.params('customerId')" }`

Now the path param customerId is passed through to the AWS Lambda function as your JSON event:

```
{
  "input": "{\"customerId\":\"marcel@example.com\"}",
  "response": {
    "Item": {
      "password": "abc#123",
      "email": "marcel@example.com"
    }
  }
}
```