# Use Path Parameters in serverless framework

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

```
 functions:
  update:
    handler: todos/update.update
    events:
      - http:
          path: /update/{title}
          method: put
```

How do I have to define the path param in order to pass it to my AWS Lambda function using serverless framework?

The language I want to use for lambda is Python3.

Comment: Similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39097572/use-path-params-in-serverless-framework-1-0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is correct, you can access the parameter you defined in the `serverless.yml` from `event['pathParameters']['title']` inside the lambda.

hope this helps